# PhP Change a variables value from front end?

Tags: php

Hello everyone and thanks for your time in advance!
I am trying to finish a project for my university and I am missing something really small.. So basically I have a variable in which I have set a specific value and as a front end user(as the Administrator of that page) I want to make a change on that value. It's like the following.. I have a specific number set and I want to be able to edit/update the value of it from a text box, or somehow from the browser.

Lets say I have this as source code:

```
$row = 0;
$totalpeoplenumber = 50;
$peoplenumber = 0;
$sql="SELECT peoplenumber FROM bookingform";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die ("ERROR  01".mysqli_error($con));


foreach($result as $result_data => $result_row)
{
    echo $result_data['peoplenumber'];
    $peoplenumber += $result_row['peoplenumber'];
}
echo ('<h2>Seats Availability</h2>');
echo ("<br>");
echo ('<b>Reserved Seats number: </b>');
echo $peoplenumber."<br>";
echo ("<br>");
$totalpeoplenumber = $totalpeoplenumber - $peoplenumber;

echo "<b>The number of available seats is: $totalpeoplenumber</b> </br></br>";

echo "<button>Edit total seats</button>";
```

So here I need to somehow change the value of $totalpeoplenumber as the administrator of the webpage and not as a programmer.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Set a form where you define the total number and save it as a parameter on DB

Answer (score 0):

For sake of simplicity you can do something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['totalpeoplenumber')){
    $totalpeoplenumber = $_GET['totalpeoplenumber '];
}
```

Then in your browser all you have to do is use the address: localhost/myAdminPage.php?totalpeoplenumber=60
it will set the total number of people to 60.

Note that you don't have to edit the URL itself, you can use a form where the submit sends to the same page (in that case you should use POST instead of GET):

```
<form action="myAdminPage.php" method="GET">
    Insert the totalpeoplenumber: <input type="text" name="totalpeoplenumber"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>
```

This propably will do for the form. In your script all you have to do is put the following code:

```
if(isset($_POST['totalpeoplenumber'])){
    $totalpeoplenumber = $_POST['totalpeoplenumber'];
}
```

done :)